# Can I enter France with Romanian residence permit as a non EU?

Tags: schengen, paperwork, france

I have a travel document issued by Israel, I don’t have an Israeli passport yet I’m a student in Romania and I have work/student residence permit, I traveled before to Schengen countries with no problem but never to France, I want to make sure that it’s okay also

Comment: Your entering into Schegen previously might have been illegal, as visas/residence permits from Romania do not give you the right to enter Schegen Area even if the contrary is right (a Schegen permit allows you to enter Romania visa-free). What is your nationality (passport you hold) as your student/residence permit is not enough to warrant entry f I'm not mistaken (take this with a grain of salt)

Comment: What kind of travel document do you have? As Jean says, your Romanian residence permit doesn't entitle you to enter Schengen without a visa if you aren't otherwise permitted to, and there is no harmonisation for acceptance of non-passport travel documents across Schengen. Some Schengen countries accept some non-passport travel documents from some countries for visa free travel.

Comment: I have an Israeli travel document which is not same as passport because I don’t have Israeli nationality but I am an Israeli citizen if this makes sense

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a visa to enter France if you hold a Travel Document in Lieu of National Passport, and the travel document shows your citizenship as Israeli. This is the typical case if you are a recent immigrant to Israel.

The [official French government visa site](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en_US/web/france-visas/ai-je-besoin-d-un-visa?p_p_id=NeedVisaApplication_WAR_fvfoportalvisasportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&_NeedVisaApplication_WAR_fvfoportalvisasportlet_implicitModel=true) states you do not need a visa in this case. It is also shown in Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents. When traveling with the Travel Docuument in Lieu of National Passport, you should tell airlines that you are an Israeli citizen.

[image: France visa assistant results]

If your travel document does *not* say "in Lieu of National Passport" on the cover, or shows a citizenship other than Israeli, then you need a visa.